# Como exibir o "id" em Json (api)

Tags: javascript, react

estou desenvolvendo um projeto no React e me deparei com um problema, fiz um map em uma lista que funciona corretamente, ou seja, se eu adicionar os objetos na api ele aparece na tela, porém gostaria de criar a função "criar" com o método post e gerar o campo "id" no json, como eu faço isso?

Segue abaixo meu código:

```js
import React from 'react';

import api from '../../api/api';

class Experiences extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      experiences: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await api.get();
    console.log(response);
    const data = response.data.experiences.map(exp => ({
      ...exp,
    }));

    this.setState({ experiences: data });
  }

  render() {
    const { experiences } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        {experiences.map(exp => (
          <section key={exp.company} className="content">
            <div className="experience-text">
              <p className="experience-text__first">
                {exp.company}
                <span className="experience__date">{exp.time}</span>
              </p>
              <p className="experience-text_second">{exp.occupation}</p>
              <p className="experience-text_second">{exp.activities}</p>
            </div>
          </section>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Experiences;
```

ao chamar a api no insomnia, obtenho o seguinte resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém gostaria de saber como fazer um CRUD e pegar o ID...

muito obrigado pela atenção de todos

Comment: Então, o correto é que a sua API já retorne o ID destes dados no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thiago, quando você enviar o **POST** para o seu endpoint e ele salvar no banco de dados ele automaticamente ira gerar um número de ID único para o seu registro. 
Para adicionar o valor do ID de cada campo você deve ajustar o **GET** da sua API ele deve retornar o valor de ID juntamente com os outros dados.

Com isso você não precisar se preocupar de fazer isso no seu FrontEnd, pois o próprio banco de dados já vai tratar os IDS para você!

Espero ter te ajudado!